# How to hide a bunch of labels in an IBOutletCollection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, iboutletcollection

New to Objective-C and iOS development, would love a hand here!

I have written up some code such that

```
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *allLabels;
```

In IB I have linked up all my labels in my view to this collection, where I want to hide them for a certain condition. However, I am not sure how to do so. Obviously to hide a single label I'd use

```
labelX.hidden = YES;
```

however it is not ideal for me to do this without a collection, as I have many labels to hide.

Thanks for your tips in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this...

```
[allLabels setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"hidden"];
```

Comment: @Vladimir which will be faster.. ? the one suggested by mit3z or by me.. ? just out of curiosity.

Comment: Made some quick tests, so no guarantee that they are adequate. Your method (tested on iPod touch with array of 50 labels) runs 0.0022 - 0.0029 sec, mit3z's method runs: 0.0015-0.002s so is a bit faster

Comment: @Vladimir would you say blocks are generally faster than methods..? is it that why it is happening?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! However, what would I use in opposition of this - ie to re-show the labels? Thank you again!

Comment: @BenToscano NO instead of YES.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, not sure why exactly it works slower. Possible reasons - time need to boxing/unboxing bool value to NSNumber, time to resolve actual selector for key name

Comment: Ah, I originally tried that and got an error but it was something else so it worked now. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Just enumerate collection and do whatever you want with contents:

```
[allLabels enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(UILabel *label, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    label.hidden = YES;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version for Array type:

```
(allLabels as NSArray).setValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: "hidden")
```

Comment: `allLabels.forEach { $0.hidden = true }` would be more swifty

Comment: Nice, @EmilioPelaez! You should create an answer if your implementation. ;)